# ¿Alguien sabe como hacer unMount a un componente canvas React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un sitio web con React en donde cada página utiliza un componente header estilado con canvas. Pero al momento de mandarlo llamar en cada una de ellas el sitio se va haciendo mas y mas lento, alguien me podria indicar una good practice para mejorar el rendimiento del sitio?

Comment: Me imagino que debe ser el script que utilizas para el canvas. Un posible escenario es el caso en el cual estas creando partículas continuamente sin eliminar las antiguas. Otra posibilidad sería una animación de formas geométricas dibujadas sin utilizar `beginPath()`. Otro posible escenario seria una animación donde llamas requestAnimationFrame o setInterval sin haver limpiado primero con `cancelAnimationFrame` o `clearInterval`. Hay tantas posibilidades. Si ninguna de estas ideas no te ayuda por favor añade tu código.